# NullPointException when parsing xml in android

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to parse xml from the code bellow:

```
XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser();
String xml = xmlParser.getXmlFromUrl(URL2);
Document doc = xmlParser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
Element e = (Element) nl.item(0);
```

that's working properly when URL2 = http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml
But when im using my server: URL2 = http://udios.bugs3.com/test.xml it falls in the last line:

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
```

with the following exception:

```
NullPointerException
Unexpected token (position:TEXT ï»¿@1:4 in java.io.StringReader@41391770)
```

The 2 xml files are identical, and i don't thing that the problem is in the server, maybe encoding problem?
I would appreciate if someone will help me
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this link is used full...

check this [Link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser)

---

```
i have shown with only <name>...</name> tag, do the same with <id>...</id> , <cost>...</cost> and <description>...</description>
```

---

```
     TextView name[];

try {

     /** Handling XML */
     SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
     SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
     XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

     /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
     URL sourceUrl = new URL(URL2);

     /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
     MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
     xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
     xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

} catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}



     /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
     sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

     /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
     name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];


     /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
     for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
          name[i] = new TextView(this);
          name[i].setText("Name = "+sitesList.getName().get(i));    
     }
```

---

```
         MyXMLHandler.java

        /* This file is used to handle the XML tags. So we need to extends with DefaultHandler.
         we need to override startElement, endElement & characters method .
         startElemnt method called when the tag starts.
         endElemnt method called when the tag ends
         characres method to get characters inside tag.

         */



         import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
         import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
         import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

         public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

         Boolean currentElement = false;
         String currentValue = null;
         public static SitesList sitesList = null;

         public static SitesList getSitesList() {
         return sitesList;
         }

         public static void setSitesList(SitesList sitesList) {
         MyXMLHandler.sitesList = sitesList;
         }

         /** Called when tag starts ( ex:- <name>Android</name>
         * -- <name> )*/
         @Override
         public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

         currentElement = true;

         if (localName.equals("menu"))
         {
         /** Start */
         sitesList = new SitesList();
         } 

         }

         /** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>Android</name>
         * -- </name> )*/
         @Override
         public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
         throws SAXException {

         currentElement = false;

         /** set value */
         if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
         sitesList.setName(currentValue);


         }

         /** Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>Android</name>
         * -- to get Android Character ) */
         @Override
         public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
         throws SAXException {

         if (currentElement) {
         currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
         currentElement = false;
         }

     }
```

}

---

```
          SitesList.java

          // Contains Getter & Setter Method


          import java.util.ArrayList;

          /** Contains getter and setter method for varialbles */
       public class SitesList {

          /** Variables */
          private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

          /** In Setter method default it will return arraylist
          * change that to add */

          public ArrayList<String> getName() {
          return name;
          }

          public void setName(String name) {
          this.name.add(name);
          }


       }
```

Comment: Thats the best way to parse non english xml values :)
thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

found workaround:
took the xml - open with notepad - save as (ANSI)

Comment: As far as i understand your question you were having problem of parsing xml fetching from server then what kind of temporary solution is this, you should have shown the solution instead of temporary workaround.

Comment: ill be more specific: it was a language problem as I tried to parse in hebrew and it didn't work untill i changed the the type of xml to ANSI.